# What is the difference between vc10, vc11 and vc12 libraries in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.11 and I have 2 folders x64 and x86 both containing vc10, vc11 and vc12 folders, each containing lib folders with the libraries. The libraries look pretty much the same in all folders, with some small differences in size. Firstly, what is the difference between the x64 and x86 folders? Secondly, what is the difference between the vc10, vc11 and vc12 libraries?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

They are different builds for each version of Microsoft's Visual Studio compiler.

- vc17: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2022
- vc16: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2019
- vc15: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2017
- vc14: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2015
- vc12: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2013
- vc11: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2012
- vc10: The compiler packaged with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @Bowecho Probably not. :P

Comment: so can we use vc12 old libs with vc16 compiler or not ??

Answer (score 2):

It refers to Visual C++ version used for the build. x64 and x86 is the chip architecture 64 vs 32 bit.

Comment: I understand, but what is the difference between vc10, vc11 and vc12 libs inside 32 or 64 architecture?

Comment: the Visual C++ version

Comment: I am using Codeblocks 13.12, so which libs would be compatible? Because I am using vc12 libs and the compiler (gnu gcc) cannot recognize some functions, which gives me errors in reading an image for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to MS Visual Studio version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History.

[image: Visual Studio version history]