# How to fix error MSVCP120D.dll in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

Hello I have downloaded and unzipped OpenCV-2.4.10.exe on my PC. Then created a new Win32 Console application project in VS 2015, set all the Paths in Project properties, set the environmental variables in Win8.1. When I'm trying to start the program in debugging mode I get the *"The program can't start because MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem*".

Then, I downloaded the Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 But the problem still remains. What should I do to use OpenCV in VS 2015?

Comment: *Then, I downloaded the Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015* -- And after you downloaded it, what did you do with the files?  Also, `MSVCP120D.DLL` is **not** a release DLL.  It is a debug runtime DLL, and is part of the Visual Studio compiler tools.  It is not part of the redistributable files.  Any Visual Studio DLL that ends with `D` in the name is a debug DLL

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707992/msvcp120d-dll-missing

Comment: vc120 is visual studio 2013 c++ compiler. Download opencv source code and compile it with visual studio 2015 (vc140). You could install visual studio 2013 redistributable, but you SHOULD NOT compile with incompatible libraries!

Comment: Or you can use OpenCV 3.1 which have prebuilt binaries for VS2015.

Answer (score 5):

OpenCV-2.4.10.exe comes with runtime binary dlls built to work with runtimes from **vc10** (vs2010), **vc11** (vs2012) and **vc12** (vs2013).

These DLL files use MSVCP100.dll, MSVCP110.dll and MSVCP120.dll respectively, and if you have installed Visual Studio 2015 you should find them in your System32 (or SysWOW64) directory.

The MSVCP120**D**.dll error appears when your application tries to load the **DEBUG** version of the DLL binaries. You do not have MSVCP120**D**.dll unless you have Visual Studio 2013 installed on your system. To solve this problem, use the Release runtime instead of the Debug runtime.

All you need to do is exclude the **DEBUG** lib files from your project. This means including only the lib files without the suffix 'd'. (ie. include opencv_core2410.lib instead of opencv_core2410**d**.lib)

HTH

Extras:
You don't really need to load the Debug binaries, unless you need to debug openCV's source code. If you do, there's still a way. Download the openCV source code, use CMake to create a VS2015 project. You can then build your own dll binaries using the latest runtime from VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 uses vc14 while OpenCV2.4.10 doesn't come with pre-built binaries associated with vc14. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31189171/5022962) should help you to understand. Accordingly you should choose the right folder (vc14) for *Linker>General>Additional Library Directories* in project properties.

You can use cmake to build binaries using VS2015 or you can download a later version of OpenCV which has prebuilt binaries for vc14.