# msvcp120d.dll is missing for visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed visual studio 2013 and tested a sample program in it, When I tried running my test program it says,

msvcp120d.dll is missing from your computer, try reinstalling.

i searched for the cause of the problem and found that probably I haven't installed some of the redistributable required for the vs2013. Here is a list of all of the redistributable(s) installed.

[image]

I checked and believe that I have both x86 and x64 version of visual c++ 2013 redistributable. I checked system32 and syswow64 folders in my windows. msvcp120d.dll is missing from syswow64 folder. What should I do?

Comment: `msvcp120.dll` is part of the redistributable `msvcp120d.dll` is not. The `d` identifies the dll as debug version of the library. This dll should be in the installation directory of your Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSVCP120d.dll missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707992/msvcp120d-dll-missing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix error MSVCP120D.dll in Visual Studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111291/how-to-fix-error-msvcp120d-dll-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: I guess its not there that's why it says msvcp120d.dll is missing.

Comment: I guess you are running a debug build of your program outside of the debugger. See the other questions (and their answer) I mentioned above.

Comment: yeah the solution in the above question worked for me.
thanks for that.